# Sampling BC5_SNORM texture yields incorrect value range

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-11, direct3d11

I'm working with Direct3d 11, and I've come across something strange. I have taken a normal map and encoded it to a DDS file twice. Once with **R8G8B8A8_SNORM** encoding, and once with **BC5_SNORM**.

Next I load each texture using **D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile** in conjunction with **D3DX11GetImageInfoFromFile**. When I sample these textures in my pixel shader I find that the **R8G8B8A8_SNORM** texture is returning values in the range [-1,1], which is what I would expect for a SNORM texture. However, the **BC5_SNORM** texture is returning values in the range [0,1], which doesn't make any sense to me.

I double an triple checked with my debugger and PIX. The format of the texture is correct (**BC5_*S*NORM**), so I am at a loss for why it's not returning signed values.

Comment: Are you certain the SSD file has been encoded correctly in the second case?

Comment: @JohnB I don't know what you mean. I used **D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile** to load a PNG normal map as a BC5_SNORM texture and then I saved it to a DDS file with **D3DX11SaveTextureToFile**. I don't know what could possibly be wrong with that.

Comment: Ok it was just a thought that maybe it was converted wrongly

Comment: Can you upload your dds files?

Comment: You may have more luck using [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926) which is provided as shared-source, which would allow you to dig into the behavior more deeply. As noted, a sample .DDS would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the same issue as you and I also got the same behaviour when doing a conversion from a R8G8B8A8_SNORM texture (with -1 to +1 values) to BC5_SNORM (producing only 0 to 1 values) when doing the conversion through **D3Dx11LoadTextureFromTexture**.  There does appear to be a fault in D3DX11, at least regarding BC5_SNORM, in that, regardless of all kinds of input formats, the (BC5)SNORM output is always in the 0 to 1 range.

As suggested by @chuckwalbourn I can confirm that the [DirectXTex](http://directxtex.codeplex.com/) utilities, which supersedes the now deprecated D3DX11, does respect and correctly handle signed values for BC5_SNORM outputs.

You can either have your program write out a temporary .dds (using **D3DX11SaveTextureToFile** with a R8G8B8A8_SNORM texture) and then invoke the standalone DirectXTex 'texconv.exe' utility to convert to BC5_SNORM, or wrangle the DirectXTex library into your program and use the 'Convert(...)' function appropriately.